# How to get state variable names from names(string) value in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

**1. I set name in statesCorelatedFields and setStatesCorelatedFields inside below codes,
how can I get state and setState variables from there? (please see below example)**

**2. Does my below approach right?**

**3. Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.**

I am using react native 0.68.5.
**Previously, I used class component**, now I am migrating to function component.

I have a reuseable file and App file like below:

**reuseable.js**

```
// import ...


export const handleFocus = (
  state,
  setState,
  focusStyle,
  // array of state variables of corelated fields
  statesCorelatedFields,
  // array of setState methods of corelated fields
  setStatesCorelatedFields,
  // blur style if no text value
  blurNoTextStyle,
) => {
  const stateData = { ...state };
  stateData.styleName = { ...focusStyle };

  // for corelated fields: empty value and set blurNoTextStyle
  if (statesCorelatedFields.length) {
    let stateCorelatedFieldData;

    for (i = 0; i < statesCorelatedFields.length; i++) {
      stateCorelatedFieldData = { ...statesCorelatedFields[i] };
      stateCorelatedFieldData.value = '';
      stateCorelatedFieldData.styleName = { ...blurNoTextStyle };

      setStatesCorelatedFields[i](stateCorelatedFieldData);
    }

  }

  setState(stateData);
};

// export const handleChangeText=(state, setState, text, ...)=>{...}
// export const handleBlur=(state, setState, ...)=>{...}
// ...
```

**App.js**

```
// import ...
// import all methods from reuseable.js


const App = () => {

  const [email, setEmail] = useState({
    name: 'email',
    value: '',
    styleName: { ...styles.blurNoTextStyle },
    error: '',
    statesCorelatedFields: [],
    setStatesCorelatedFields: [],
  });

  const [countryCode, setCountryCode] = useState({
    name: 'countryCode',
    value: '',
    styleName: { ...styles.blurNoTextStyle },
    error: '',
    // I set name here; how can I get state and setState variable from here
    statesCorelatedFields: ['phoneNumber'],
    setStatesCorelatedFields: ['setPhoneNumber'],
  });

  const [phoneNumber, setPhoneNumber] = useState({
    name: 'phoneNumber',
    value: '',
    styleName: { ...styles.blurNoTextStyle },
    error: '',
    statesCorelatedFields: [],
    setStatesCorelatedFields: [],
  });


  return (
    <>
      {/* components */}
      <TextInput
        value={countryCode.value}
        onChangeText={(text) => handleChangeText(countryCode, setCountryCode, text)}
        onFocus={() => handleFocus(countryCode, setCountryCode, styles.focusStyle, countryCode.statesCorelatedFields, countryCode.setStatesCorelatedFields)}
        onBlur={() => handleBlur(countryCode, setCountryCode)}
      />
      {/* other components */}
    </>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  // styles goes here
});


export default App;
```

*Thanks in advance.*

Answer (score 0):

Moves this setStatesCorelatedFields out of the loop body you are updating the state on every iteration which doesn't need. It causes to slow down your component

you can do like this:

```
  if (statesCorelatedFields.length) {
    let stateCorelatedFieldData;

    for (i = 0; i < statesCorelatedFields.length; i++) {
      stateCorelatedFieldData = { ...statesCorelatedFields[i] };
      stateCorelatedFieldData.value = "";
      stateCorelatedFieldData.styleName = { ...blurNoTextStyle };
    }
    setStatesCorelatedFields[i](stateCorelatedFieldData);
  }
```

Comment: @FaizarAli A TextInput can have more than one corelated fields and If I move setStatesCorelatedFields out of for loop, then how can I write `setStatesCorelatedFields[i](stateCorelatedFieldData)` .  I could not find answer about 'Does my approach right?' and on App.js file setting about corelated field, so that, I can perform handleFocus method correctly. Thanks.